# How to call each iterated value for a variable inside iteration in R

Tags: r

I have a loop for-iteration in R and I have a variable `b` which is storing a single value inside an iteration, the value of `b` can change at each iteration, the problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to call for each value of `b` during each iteration and I really need this during iteration. For example I want add the value of `b` when iteration was at level 2 to the same value of `b` when iteration was at level 4. If I print out `b`, it gives me the correct answer but I don't know how to call each value of b during iteration.

Note: `b` is not a vector, it a single value variable that is calculated inside iteration. Kindly see my codes below

```
# Assignment for the resistant line
x <- c(51.3, 49.9, 50, 49.2, 48.5, 47.8, 47.3, 45.1, 46.3, 42.1, 44.2, 43.5, 42.3, 
    40.2, 31.8, 34)
y <- c(102.5, 104.5, 100.4, 95.9, 87, 95, 88.6, 89.2, 78.9, 84.6, 81.7, 72.2, 65.1, 
    68.1, 67.3, 52.5)
n <- 3

df = data.frame(x, y)
data = df[order(x), ]


# Partition <- function(x,n) split(x,factor(sort(rank(x)%%n)))

x = data$x
y = data$y

for (i in 1:10) {

    Partition1 <- split(x, factor(sort(rank(x)%%n)))
    Partition1
    xl = median(Partition1[[1]])
    xm = median(Partition1[[2]])
    xr = median(Partition1[[3]])

    Partition2 <- split(y, factor(sort(rank(y)%%n)))
    Partition2
    yl = median(Partition2[[1]])
    ym = median(Partition2[[2]])
    yr = median(Partition2[[3]])


    b = round((yr - yl)/(xr - xl), digits = 3)


    a = round(((yl + ym + yr) - (b * (xl + xm + xr)))/3, digits = 2)

    yfit = a + (b * x)
    yres = round(y - yfit, digits = 2)
    df1 = data.frame(x, y, yfit, yres)
    df2 = data.frame(xl, xm, xr, yl, ym, yr, b, a)
    if (i > 0) {
        y = yres
    }
    # print(df1) 
    # print(df2)
    print(b)
}
```

The `b` output is below

```
[1] 3.412
[1] -0.872
[1] 0.624
[1] -0.484
[1] 0.374
[1] -0.293
[1] 0.23
[1] -0.18
[1] 0.14`
[1] -0.109
```

For example, if I want to retrieve `b` when iteration level is 3 and 4, how do I call it inside my program?

Comment: Are you asking how to use the value of `b` within an iteration or are you asking how to compile the values that `b` takes in each iteration so that you will have it after the loop is complete?

Comment: I want to know the value of each b inside the iteration, for example, I want to compute another variable c inside the iteration that will use the value of b. for example I want to compute ci = bi+bi-1, where i is my iteartion, for instance, when iteration is at level 3, I want to compute c3= b3-b2. where b3 is the value of b when iteration is at level 3 and b2 is the value of b when iteration is at level 2,an so on

Answer (score 0):

`b` is already a vector - a vector of length one. But you can store `b` as a multi-length vector like this `b[i] <- round((yr-yl)/(xr-xl),digits=3)`, and then access whichever iteration of b you need with `b[i]`.

Comment: The problem is that when I use b[i], I got different answers for which are definately not correct answers. b[i]= round((yr-yl)/(xr-xl),digits=3)
print(b[i])

a= round(((yl+ym+yr) -(b*(xl+xm+xr)))/3,digits=2)

Comment: You need to change every instance of `b` to `b[i]` within your `for` loop. If you do not, then R will attempt to recycle the other variables when using `b` in an operation.

Comment: Thanks Luke, let me do that I will feed you back

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. Please let me know if I have misunderstood.

```
b.permanent <- NA

for(i in 1:10){

  Partition1 <- split(x,factor(sort(rank(x)%%n)))
  Partition1
  xl= median(Partition1[[1]])
  xm= median(Partition1[[2]])
  xr= median(Partition1[[3]])

  Partition2 <- split(y,factor(sort(rank(y)%%n)))
  Partition2
  yl= median(Partition2[[1]])
  ym= median(Partition2[[2]])
  yr= median(Partition2[[3]])


  b = round((yr-yl)/(xr-xl),digits=3)

  a = round(((yl+ym+yr) -(b*(xl+xm+xr)))/3,digits=2)

  yfit= a + (b*x)
  yres=round(y-yfit,digits=2)
  df1 = data.frame(x,y,yfit,yres)
  df2=data.frame(xl,xm,xr,yl,ym,yr,b,a)
  if(i>0){
    y =yres
  }
  b.permanent <- c(b.permanent, b)
}

b.permanent <- b.permanent[!is.na(b.permanent)]
b.permanent
 [1]  0.085 -0.067  0.053 -0.042  0.032 -0.025  0.020 -0.016  0.012 -0.009
```